# If or switch statement with string and bool C#

Tags: c#, if-statement, datagridview, switch-statement

In the `form1`, I'm loading a `datagridview` with data from my database. When I double click on a row of the `datagridview`, it launches the `form2` and it will be filled with the info of that row. I'm able to fill the `textboxes` and `comboboxes` of the `form2`, but my problem comes here, in the database I have a column that requires an answer of yes or no, that means, is a string, and according to that answer I want to check one of two `radiobuttons` of the `form2`, when I try to use an if statement like this one:

```
if (datacontext.married = "yes") 
{ 
radiobutton1.checked 
} 
else 
{
radiobutton2.checked
}
```

It gives me an error saying that I cannot convert ..... bool to string or viceversa, and I tried with a switch statement too.

I'm still a beginner in C# and if I'm using something in the wrong way I would be glad to hear your suggestions.
What can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not comparing the values you need to use `==`

```
if (datacontext.married == "yes") 
{ 
 radiobutton1.checked 
} 
else 
{
 radiobutton2.checked
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change it to:

```
if (datacontext.married == "yes") // Note double ==
{
    radiobutton1.checked = true; // Or what you want to do.
} 
else 
{
    radiobutton2.checked = true
}
```

One `=` is assigning. Double `==` is comparing.

See the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53k8ybth.aspx) for more info.

> For predefined value types, the equality operator (==) returns true if
>   the values of its operands are equal, false otherwise. For reference
>   types other than string, == returns true if its two operands refer to
>   the same object. For the string type, == compares the values of the
>   strings.